# Angular Validators.required gets strange message in form field

Tags: angular

I have the problem that after adding Validators.required I get a really strange message put into the form field

The message: "function(M){return se(M)}"

Do you know why this happens?

```
        super.ngOnInit();
        this.justificationControl = new UntypedFormControl(Validators.required);
        this.form = new UntypedFormGroup({
            justificationControl: this.justificationControl
        });
        this.markForCheck();
        this.ready = true;
```

```
        <form *ngIf="ready" novalidate>
            <p>{{"common.accept" | translate:transition.description}}</p>
            <form-textarea label="common.justification" [rows]="5" [control]="justificationControl" [autofocus]="true"></form-textarea>
        </form>
```

(form-textare is only a passthrough to the default textarea)

Comment: you are creating a control with value `Validators.required`, and zero validators

Comment: Error persists with:
this.justificationControl = new UntypedFormControl(['', Validators.required]);

Comment: new UntypedFormControl('', [Validators.required]);

Comment: Thank you very much @Evgeny Gurevich, i was having so much confusion, to long on the same ticket >.<

Answer (score 1):

Evgeny found the correct answer, thank you very much

```
new UntypedFormControl('', [Validators.required]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.justificationControl = new UntypedFormControl({
  Validators: [Validators.required],
});
```

As a result, the Validators.required property is added to the array of validators for your control. If the control fails the validation, Angular will handle showing the relevant error message.

```
super.ngOnInit();
this.justificationControl = new UntypedFormControl({
  Validators: [Validators.required],
});
this.form = new UntypedFormGroup({
  justificationControl: this.justificationControl,
});
this.markForCheck();
this.ready = true;
```